# According to Hebrews 6:13-16 God swears by Himself an oath to Abraham, but at Genesis 22:15-16 why does it say the angel of the Lord swore the oath?

Tags: genesis, hebrews, abraham

According to "The Jewish Encyclopedia," it describes the "Jewish Law of Agency." The Law of Agency deals with the status of a person (known as the agent) acting by direction of another (the principal), and thereby legally binding the principal in his connection with a third person.

The person who binds a principal in this manner is his agent, known in Jewish law as sheluach or sheliach (one that is sent); the relation of the former to the latter is is known as agency (shelichut). This principal is enunciated thus: A man's agent is like himself.

Genesis 17:1-2 states the following. "Now when Abram was ninety-nine years old, the Lord appeared to Abram and said to him. "I am God Almighty; Walk before Me, and be blameless, Vs2, And I will multiply you exceedingly." God appears to Abram and says He will multiply Abram descendants.

At Genesis 22 God test Abraham by asking him to sacrifice his son, his only son Isaac. At vs10, "And Abraham stretched out his hand, and took the knife to slay his son." Vs11, BUT the angel of the Lord called to him from heaven, and said, "Abraham, Abraham!" And he said, "Here I am."

Vs12, And he said, (the angel said) Do not stretch out your hand against the lad, and do nothing to him; for now I know that you fear God, since you have not withheld your son, your only son, from Me." At verses 13-14 the Lord provides a ram for Abraham to sacrifice.

Vs15, "Then the angel of the Lord called to Abraham a second time from heaven, vs16, and said, "By Myself I have sworn, declares the Lord because you have done this thing, and have not withheld your son, your only son." Vs17, "indeed I will greatly bless you and multiply your seed as the stars of the heavens, and as the sand which is on the seashore; and your seed shall possess the gate of their enemies." Vs18, "And in your seed all the nations of the earth shall be blessed because you have obeyed My voice."

So getting back to my question? "Can an angel swear an oath on behalf of God Himself?" Would the Jewish Law of Agency be applicable here? I ask because Hebrews 6:13-16 says, "For when God made the promise to Abraham, since He could not swear by no one greater, He swore by Himself, vs14, saying, I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you."

Vs15, "And thus, having patiently waited he obtained the promise. Vs16, For men swear by one greater than themselves, and with them an oath given as confirmation is an end of every dispute."

Comment: The angel of the Lord is quoting God Almighty when he says.    ”By myself I have sworn because you have done this thing.....I will bless you and multiply your seed....because you have obeyed my voice.”   The angel of the Lord is not swearing at all.

Comment: @Kris How do you know he's quoting God Almighty, from where? Secondly, the angel of the Lord is speaking in the first person. Thirdly, why does the angel of the Lord call out from heaven two times? At Exodus 20:22, the Lord says to Moses, "You yourselves have seen that I have spoken to you from heaven." Fourthly, at Genesis 17:1-2 God Almighty physically appears to Abram and says He will establish His covenant between Him and Abram and will multiply Abram exceedingly."   At Genesis 17:22 it confirms that God appeared to him physically. "And when God finished talking, God went up from Abraham."

Comment: I know because vs 15 -16  says the angel of the Lord called to Abe  and said By myself I have sworn *”declares the Lord”*

Comment: https://biblehub.com/text/genesis/22-16.htm.  Read the verses here to see that YHWH Yahweh is how the Original Hebrew reads instead of  Lord.   This  clears the confusion.  The angel of YHWH says to Abe “by myself I have sworn declares YHWH ......”.  So it is Yahweh who is swearing on himself and it is the angel of Yahweh  who tells Abe what Yahweh declares.

Comment: Stephen understood that is was angelic representative speaking to Moses. Acts 7:37,38

Comment: @Kris At Genesis 22:1-2 was the angel of the Lord quoting God in those two verses or was God Himself speaking? Your also missing other very important points. If you witnessed a crime and had to testify in court you would not send someone else to testify for you. Even you could not appear in person the judge would send someone to "depose" you. According to the uniform Law on Notarial Acts one person may not take an oath or affirmation for another, this act being highly personal commitment of conscience. As stated at Hebrews 6 an angel or anyone else is not greater than God Himself, that's it.

Comment: True an angel cant swear on behalf of Jehovah   And obviously the angel of Jehovah is not swearing an oath to Abraham

Comment: This question on Biblical interpretation is missing the fairly standard "According to whom" clause.

Comment: I would suggest the question be edited to focus on the fact that the Lord is the one who swears by himself. He swears to do it. And he then does it. The _Malak_ of God is also Lord.

Comment: @PeterTurner I edited the the thread in the form of a question? Please let me know if it meets the appropriate requirements. Thank You!

Comment: @Mr.Bond any qualms with a migration to hermenueitics?  I think it's pretty clear what you're asking for here.  If you wanted an answer from a churches dogma (which is just the Greek for opinion) as to whether an angel could do a thing, I think you'd have specified that in your question.

Comment: @PeterTurner I'll leave it up to you but I prefer to leave it here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kris Your right, an angel cannot swear an oath on behalf of God just like I stated. Your "assuming" that the angel of the Lord is an actual angel. You also "assume" (without any evidence) but speculation that Michael the arc angel is the angel of the Lord. Nigel explained the word "malak" and what it means in context. Regarding Stephen! Read what he says at Acts 7:30-34. He is referencing Exodus 3:2-7. At vs4, "God called to him/Moses from the midst of the bush, and said etc. Vs6, I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob. This event is patterned after Genesis 22.

Answer (score 9):

Malachi makes clear that there is a *malak* (messenger/angel) that is 'the Lord himself'.

> Behold, I will send my messenger, and he shall prepare the way ***before me***: and the Lord, whom ye seek, shall suddenly come to his temple, even the messenger of the covenant, whom ye delight in: behold, he shall come, saith the LORD of hosts. [Malachi 3:1 KJV]

There is a messenger/*malak* who is John the Baptist. And there is a messenger/*malak* who is the Lord himself, come to his temple, who is the Messenger of the Covenant. Or, as Hebrews has it, the *Apostle* and High Priest of our confession, Christ Jesus.

Jesus adjusts the septuagint by one letter (my face to thy face) and adds clarity.

> For this is he, of whom it is written, Behold, I send my messenger before ***thy*** face, which shall prepare thy way before thee. [Matthew 11:10 KJV]

Mark follows Jesus' words and also states 'thy face':

> As it is written in the prophets, Behold, I send my messenger before ***thy face***, which shall prepare thy way ***before thee.***  [Mark 1:2 KJV]

making clear that the Messenger of the Covenant is the Lord himself (*in the Person of the Son*).

---

The oath is made by the *malak*. And there is a *malak* who is the Lord himself.

Therefore if the *malak* who sware is Lord himself, then, yes, that *malak* may sware on behalf of the Lord.

Comment: Plus 1. Good job! The Hebrew word "malak" simply means messenger/angel as you pointed out. Depending on the context the word can refer to an actual angel like Michael or Gabriel, or it can refer to a human being like John the Baptist. In fact the prophet, "Malachi" who wrote the book, well his name is from the Hebrew word "malak." I don't think him or John the Baptist were angels, except maybe to their mothers!

Comment: John 3:16 sets the precedent that a messenger is inferior to the one who sends him.   So no “Malak” is God.

Comment: @Kris . . . . .  or an only begotten Son possesses (by a divine begetting in One Holy Spirit) the same divine life as the Father, and is thus equal deity in _divine nature_, yet still a faithful, filial servant in _divine relationship_. (But I have the most strange feeling of _deja vue_ that you and I have been here many times before, sir.)

Comment: The idea of a messenger being sent by God to speak with authority granted to him by God is something people living in pre trinitarian times would understand. Only after you absorb the coequal coeternal.consubstantiality homoousian  theory  of the creeds does one find the need to contort simple concepts into special unique meanings, thus saying sometimes a Malak is actually the Lord who sent the Malak.

Comment: @Kris Not true at all. I know, you and your organization  blame the creeds, the hypostatic union and just in general it's all the Trinitarians fault. If you knew your Bible by doing  YOUR OWN homework (not JW stuff) the first "shilach was Abraham at Genesis 24. He sent a servant (the agent) to find a wife for his Son Isaac where Abraham is the "principal." Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaliah And btw, John 3:16 has nothing to do with the "shaliach" princple. Jesus Christ as the Son is equal in nature to His Father. Just like your equal in nature to your father. Are you inferior to him?

Comment: @Mr.Bond  my father is not eternally existing. Jehovah is eternally existing. Jesus had a beginning and thus is not equal to Jehovah.

Comment: @Kris That's it, change the subject. You can't even admit when your wrong on shaliavh/malakl" issue I gave you. Secondly, the Son/Jesus was not created because His Father was not created. Read what C.S.Lewis says on this issue. https://oneminuteapologist.com/what-does-the-word-begotten-mean/  Lastly I have one question for you? If Jesus was created as you say and teach, who was his human father?

Comment: Who was Jesus human father????    Adam was also created.  who was his human father?

Comment: Oops @Mr.Bond  I forgot to tag you.   I don’t understand your question about Jesus having a human father.

Comment: @Kris Adam and Eve were the first two people created that resulted in them starting the human race. God is not "biology" where He produces babies like humans do. Moreover, God is Spirit or a Spiritual being according to John 4:24. You and your organization claim Jesus was created so who was his human father? Reconcile this with 1 Corinthians 15:47. "The first man/Adam is from the earth, earthy; the second man/Jesus is from heaven." This is confirmed at John 6:38, 6:33, 6:41, 6:42, John 3:13, "No one has ascended into heaven, but He who descended from heaven; the Son of Man." Who's His Father!

Comment: Jesus has no human father.   Jesus was the first creation of God a mighty.  spirit creature living in heaven with his Father Jehovah for untold eons before anything else existed. Why are you acting as if a created spirit creature must have a human father?  Maybe you have jw beliefs and Unitarian beliefs confused.

Comment: @Kris A father does not 'make' a son. How grotesque ! A father _begets_ a son : a matter of _life_ not . . . . . construction. Divine Life, in one Holy Spirit, an eternal begetting. 'Create' a son ? Never ! I did not make my sons - I begat them, livingly.

Comment: @NigelJ  a father exists before his son exists.  Then a father takes an action that results in offspring.  For humans this is known as procreation. This[ answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/75504) to a JW question on CSE may interest you.

Comment: @Kris But that does not apply in eternity. It does not apply to God who is eternal. That is why I say an _eternal begetting_ in one Holy Spirit. It is within Deity. Within he who is, eternally, one God, blessed for ever. And there I leave it. No further comment.

Comment: @NigelJ I want to have the last word so here it is.  No further comment!